# Building OpenNN with MinGW

Tags: cmake, mingw, mingw32, opennn

I am trying to build the [OpenNN](http://www.opennn.net/) library with MinGW on Windows 10.  I'm getting lots of build errors, which make me think I haven't configured something correctly using CMake.

I used the CMake GUI to configure, selecting "MinGW Makefiles" and "use default native compilers". It seems to configure and generate without errors.

However, when I try to build it from the command line, using "mingw32-make all", it compiles for about 5 minutes, then produces thousands of "undefined reference to `std::*" errors.  These are some of them:

```
undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
undefined reference to `std::logic_error::logic_error(std::string const&)'
undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
undefined reference to `std::logic_error::~logic_error()'
undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
undefined reference to `std::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::str() const'
undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::allocator()'
undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'
undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
```

What am I doing wrong?  It mentions in the [build instructions](http://www.opennn.net/documentation/building_opennn.html) that it's compatible with "MPI and OpenMP compilations" (I assume it means compilers). Does that mean it's not compatible with MinGW? Because it mentions GNU in the [list of OpenMP compatible compilers](http://www.openmp.org/resources/openmp-compilers/).

Comment: Hmm, basic c++ functions... Looks like your MinGW environment is not configured properly. Have you able to build any C++ code in your environment? E.g. you may try "hello world" CMake example from http://derekmolloy.ie/hello-world-introductions-to-cmake. You don't specify neither `__OPENNN_MPI__` nor `__OPENNN_OMP__` for build OpenNN, am I right?

Comment: @Tsyvarev - Yup, I've had lots of projects build fine using code::blocks, which is using the MinGW environment.  I don't specift __OPENNN_MPI__ because I'm not sure how to using the CMake GUI.  I think this might be the problem.

Comment: Without OpenMPI/OpenOMP, the only project's setup is `set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)` (for g++ this means `-std=c++11` option). Then it simply builds executables and libraries. If MinGW works correctly for you, it could be a problem with CMake settings. Again, you may check that with "hello world" CMake example.